# Remote services between European States?

Tags: eu, spain, switzerland, qualifications

When providing online professional services between European States, what regulation does apply, the one of the country where the professional is or the one of the client?

Particularly, I'm concerned with a Spanish psychologist moving to Switzerland but providing remote services to clients in Spain. Would she need to register in Switzerland? Get her title recognized by Swiss authorities?  What if the clients where to be on a third EU country like France?